# HTML in PDF on the server side for the dynamic page (already rendered)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

There was a need to send a dynamic page to PDF in Django proj.

Can someone give an example in which an already rendered page is sent to print.

In [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/) example, the page is native and static. Can I somehow remodel so that the rendered page is sent to the PDF.

I tried to do this on the client side, but all the options that I used either do not support Cyrillic (jsPDF and others) or can not convert html (PDFmake and others).

So I decided to look in the direction of the server side but all the examples that I found use a static html pointing to it.

Can eat any ways through ajax requests, etc.

Comment: is this a stateless page or it depends on user session?

Comment: @DRC I did not understand the question. The page is the result of calculations and is something like a check for purchases. The page displays information about the user who calculated.

Comment: I used to render HTML to pdf in my projects, so far **[use a static html pointing to it.]**  is the most efficient way, packages used : `weasyprint`

Comment: @Lemayzeur I will definitely try.